# Loop Through List and Run Report

Tags: vba, loops

First time postings and I'm far from a VBA expert, but I've managed to stumble most of the way to my desired outcome thanks to boards like this one. I'm hoping to automate one last step and am looking for some assistance.

Background:
I run project reports for our Project Managers every Monday morning. The report template queries several tables in our database and populates all of the appropriate fields. It then creates a copy of itself, saves the formulas as values and saves the report using a naming mechanism capturing data from various fields in the report. All of this works great!

The Issue:
At any given time, I have 80-100 active projects. As it stands, I copy the list of projects to a table on the "Parameters" tab. Then, using data validation, I created a dropdown list on the "Report" tab. I then manually go 1 by 1 through the list to generate the report. Each time I change project number in cell B1, the data refreshes and runs the report for the project. I'm using this code to accomplish that:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'MsgBox Target.Address
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("b1"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Call AA_RunAll
End If
End Sub
```

What I'd like to do is create a macro that will run through each one of the projects on my list and run the report. I'm assuming it's a loop function, but I can't seem to get it to work as I want.

One other consideration to note: it takes 3-5 minutes per report to refresh all the data, generate the report and save it. I'd like to set this to run before I leave at night and have it done in the morning.

Thanks in advance.

Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be what you are looking for.

```
Dim DataValidationRange As Range
Dim Str As String
Str = Replace(Range("B1").Validation.Formula1, "=", "")
Set DataValidationRange = Range(Str)
Dim i
For Each i In DataValidationRange
    Range("B1").Value = i
    Call AA_RunAll
Next
```

Also if you need to wait for the data to update before calling AA_RunAll, you could use this:

```
Public Function MyTimer(MyDelay As Double)
    Dim MyTimerTimer As Double
    MyTimerTimer = Timer
    MyDelay = MyDelay + Timer
    
    Do While MyTimerTimer <= MyDelay
        MyTimerTimer = Timer
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Function

Private Sub GoThrough_Dropdown()
    Dim DataValidationRange As Range
    Dim Str As String
    Str = Replace(Range("B1").Validation.Formula1, "=", "")
    Set DataValidationRange = Range(Str)
    Dim i
    For Each i In DataValidationRange
        Range("B1").Value = i
        WaitForDataToUpdate
        Call AA_RunAll
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub WaitForDataToUpdate()
    Dim RangeToWaitFor As Range
    Set RangeToWaitFor = Range("H5")
    Dim Str As String
    Str = RangeToWaitFor.Value
    Do While Str = RangeToWaitFor.Value
        MyTimer 1
    Loop
End Sub
```